# Handling websocket disconnect in Python Flask server using RxPY for push based events

Tags: python, websocket, rx-py, flask-sockets

## Context

I am using *RxPY* to enable sending push based events via websockets. I am using *flask-sockets* in a *Flask* server with *gevent*. The events class contains an *rx.subject.BehaviorSubject* that acts as an event publisher, while the websocket clients subscribe to changes.

## Problem

I want to be able to detect when a client is disconnected so I could properly dispose the resources. The problem is when the socket is disconnected and `ws.send` throws an exception but it's inside the lambda.

## Solution?

Is there a way to pass the exception to the parent function instead?

An alternative solution would be to detect the websocket disconnect without calling `ws.send` and that could be checked outside the lambda, though I could not find such method in the *flask-sockets* library.

```
@sockets.route('/ws/events')
def wsEvents(ws):
    sub = None
    disp = None
    try:
        print("socket opened")
        def update_fn(x):
            print(x) 
            ws.send(json.dumps(x))

        sub = events.get_sub(None)

        if sub is not None:
            disp = sub.subscribe(lambda x: update_fn(x))
        else:
            raise Exception('Undefined sub') 

        while not ws.closed:
            gevent.sleep(1)
            pass

    except Exception as e:
        print(e) 

    finally:
        print("socket closed")
        if disp is not None:
            disp.dispose()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround, detecting the socket disconnect event using a *gevent* timeout method like this:

```
while not ws.closed:
    gevent.sleep(0.1)
    try:
        data = gevent.with_timeout(0.1, ws.receive, timeout_value="")
        if data is None:
            raise Exception("socket closed")
    except:
        break
```

Now it's possible to dispose the resources as the method returns `None` on socket disconnected event.